# get value of select option and assign it to url parameter directly

Tags: php, jquery

i have this code:

```
<li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Selecciona el periodo: <select name="period" id="p2" class="input-block-level"><option value="0" selected>Mensual</option> 
  <option value="1">Semestral</option>
  <option value="2">Anual</option></select></li>
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger" href="/modify_cart?option=add_item&item_id='.$resultado2['id'].'&period=" >Comprar ahora!</a>
```

i need to add the value of the selected option to the url link

```
/modify_cart?option=add_item&item_id='.$resultado2['id'].'&period=(the value)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: yes it is possible through **HistoryAPI**, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes its possible try this code:-

```
$(function () {
  var a = $('a.btn-block');
  a.attr('href', a.attr('href') + $('#p2').val())
});
```

and on change event of dropdow you can use this code it will change the url when selected value will be change:-

```
$(function () {  
 $('#p2').change(function(){
  var a = $('a.btn-block');
  a.attr('href', a.attr('href') + $(this).val())
  }); 
});
```

Comment: it worked so theres a chance to enable button when they select?

Comment: i didn't got you which button you are talking about but `$('#p2').change(function(){` in this event you can enable disable buttons if you have

Comment: the url i want to enble when the users choses the period

Comment: @FindelMundo gald if it worked for you. happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't be possible with PHP until after the form was submitted. You would have to use Javascript or jQuery to change the href attribute of the link depending on which option was selected.

Example in jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var optn = $('select option:selected').val();
   $('a').attr('href', '/modify_cart?option=add_item&period=' + optn); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/anudeepr/5zwz4g0x/
@MKA nearly got it right but this works.

```
$(function () {
    var a = $('a.btn-block');
    setURL()
    $('#p2').change(setURL);

    function setURL() {
        a.attr('href', a.attr('href') + $('#p2').val())
    }
})
```